# Android Room : Each bind variable in the query must have a matching method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using the android persistence library `Room` with Kotlin.

The `Dao` looks like this

```
@Dao
interface CountryDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM countries")
    fun loadAllCountried() : LiveData<List<CountryEntity>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(products: List<CountryEntity>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = :countryId")
    fun loadCountry(countryId: Int): LiveData<CountryEntity>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = :countryId")
    fun loadCountrySync(countryId: Int): CountryEntity

}
```

It seems good to me but I am getting this error

`Error: Each bind variable in the query must have a matching method parameter. Cannot find method parameters for :countryId.`

I can see the parameter is named as `countryId`, so what may be the issue?

FYI:
Here is the generated code in CountryDao_Impl.java

```
@Override
public CountryEntity loadCountrySync(int arg0) {
  final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = ?";
  final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 1);
  int _argIndex = 1;
  final Cursor _cursor = __db.query(_statement);
  try {
    final int _cursorIndexOfId = _cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id");
    final int _cursorIndexOfPopulation = _cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("population");
    final CountryEntity _result;
   if(_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     _result = new CountryEntity();
      final int _tmpId;
      _tmpId = _cursor.getInt(_cursorIndexOfId);
      _result.setId(_tmpId);
      final long _tmpPopulation;
      _tmpPopulation = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfPopulation);
      _result.setPopulation(_tmpPopulation);
    } else {
      _result = null;
    }
    return _result;
  } finally {
    _cursor.close();
    _statement.release();
  }
}
```

In this method I see `arg0` is not being used anywhere in the method.

EDIT:
This seems to be fixed in the new plugins. Several of the answers here are correct, but I can't accept every answer, Sorry.

Comment: This is a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18048

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17959

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62125909

Comment: How did you get this generated code?

Answer (score 67):

Kotlin isn't preserving the names of the arguments properly - this is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17959

You can work around this by using `:arg0`, `:arg1`, etc, as parameter names in your @Query statements:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = :arg0")
fun loadCountry(countryId: Int): LiveData<CountryEntity>

@Query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = :arg0")
fun loadCountrySync(countryId: Int): CountryEntity
```

Comment: I am getting: Each bind variable in the query must have a matching method parameter. Cannot find method parameters for :arg1, :arg0

Comment: Note that as of April 2019 having done an update to android studio on an old project, updated room to v1.1.1 i found that using arg0 was actually the problem, and i had to edit my DOA files to replace arg0 to match the function parameter name. i.e. arg0 became countryId.

Answer (score 13):

This error occurs if you do not have `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` defined in your *build.gradle* file. If you do enable the kapt plugin, the compiler will match the binding parameter with the method arguments as expected.

Answer (score 8):

With kotlin v.1.2.10 and higher in the project for me it works only by next way:

```
@Query("select * from user where pk = :userId")
fun findUserById(userId: Long): DBUser
```

names "**:userId**" in the query and "**userId**" in the method should be the same.

Answer (score 6):

For me, this issue appeared when I change/add methods in either the `DAO` interface or database `Entity` classes, and I solved it by just `Build > Clean Project` followed by `Build > Make Project`. then run it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue now can be fixed using 1.1.3-eap-85 and kotlin-kapt. 
[Official tweet](https://twitter.com/yigitboyar/status/877554535123763204)

Comment: Error:Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.3-eap-85.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous solutions worked for me. I had the @Dao files and the @Database file in different modules.

I had to put all the files (related to Room) in the same module for the error to disappear.

Comment: This was the only working solution when I trying to export the DB schema as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48674264/2664521
on this android developer training app:
https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-bus-schedule-app

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem after updating `kotlinVersion` to `1.9.0` and `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` to `1.5.0`.
I didn't dig a lot, but after some debugging I decided to try **`KSP`** (the new annotation processor for kotlin) and it fixed my problem!
From [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp#kts) I also learned that:

> Kapt is now in maintenance mode, and we recommend migrating from kapt
> to KSP wherever possible. In most cases, this migration only requires
> changes to your project's build configuration.

If you are facing the same problem in 2023, switching to **`KSP`** may help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fixed in kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.3

Comment: Not fixed for me.  I have to use var0

Comment: I am using version 1.1.61 of the kotlin grade plugin and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

As [Anton Kazakov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44824679/3998402) said this bug is fixed in kotlin plugin `1.1.3-eap-85`

but since it is not public yet you need to download it from their privet repository, not jcenter

so you need to add this line in your build.gradle

```
 maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev' }
```

example

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.1.3-eap-85'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issues has been fixed int room 1.1.0-alpha3.

More information about this issues is here :

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68118746